# Countdown javascript app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of JavaScript which is part of a countdown timer I need to know how to preset the timer to only run for 48 hours every time the page is submitted ? at the moment I place a time in a it begins to countdown to that time. Please help!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#countdown").countdown({
            date: "16 january 2013 16:45:00",
            format: "on"
        },

        function() {
            // callback function
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: is not very clear yet what are you trying to accomplish or what is the expected result of this code. Do you want the counter to always start showing 48 hours from now?

Comment: Yes 48 hours from when the form the page is connected to is submitted

Comment: I think that is the plugin http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js @PraveenKumar

Comment: That is only the jquery code. That is not the plugin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't entirely understand your question, if you could clarify that would help. I believe you're asking for a countdown via the plugin, that executes a function two days after the page is loaded.

Make sure you're including the countdown plugin and jQuery:

```
var dateCount = new Date();
dateCount.setDate(dateCount.getDate() + 2);

document.write(dateCount);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: dateCount,
        format: "on"
    },

    function() {
        // callback function
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);//two days later. you can set it to whatever you want

$("#countdown").countdown({
    date: date,
    format: "on"
},

function() {
    // callback function
});
```

Of course, don't forget putting `document.ready()` part.

Comment: date might be needed to parsed. I dont know the plugin you are using. You may try Date.parse(date). But it's certain that the variable 'date' is correct

Comment: anyway someone has copied my answer

Comment: @mustafa No, someone did not copy your answer. Your answer is incorrect and therefore would not work. Next time you downvote someone however, try leaving a comment as to why.